# JavaScript Proxy Setter doesn't make a second Proxy call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I have the following code that is using Proxy for Class setter. In my example I am tracking specific variable to update some other variables. My Setter is writing a log of all changes to Console. However if I try to modify a variable from a setter itself, variable gas modified, but the Proxy isn't called. Is it by design to avoid looping? Or am I missing something?

```js
class darthVader {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      set(obj, prop, value) {
        console.log(`Setting ${prop} to ${value}`)
        obj[prop] = value
        return true
      }
    })
  }


  set resistance(val) {
    this._resistance= val
    this.darkSide = false
  }

  get resistance() { return this._R2D2 }

}

let newHero = new darthVader()
newHero.resistance = 11
console.log(newHero.darkSide)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your trap just runs `obj[prop] = value`, which sets a property on the target `obj` not on the proxy. What you should do instead is to use the [`Reflect.set` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/set) that provides the default implementation for the set trap, and expects an optional `receiver` argument. This receiver is the object that setters will be evaluated against, and you should pass the [`receiver` argument of the `set` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set) (which will refer to the `newHero` proxy that you assigned `resistance` to).

```js
class DarthVader {
  set resistance(val) {
    this._resistance= val
    this.darkSide = false
  }

  get resistance() { return this._R2D2 }

}

let newHero = new Proxy(new DarthVader, {
  set(target, prop, value, receiver) {
    console.log(`Setting ${prop} to ${value}`)
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, value, receiver)
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^
    // obj[prop] = value
  }
});

newHero.resistance = 11
console.log(newHero.darkSide)
```

Answer (score -2):

The `obj` inside the `set` method refers to what `this` is when you do `return new Proxy(this`, and that object is *not* a proxy, but the `darthVader` instance itself - the one that's in the process of being created by the `darthVader` constructor. So, when you assign to a property of `obj`, you're putting a property directly on the `darthVader` instance, rather than on the proxy instance (which is the `newHero`). So, the proxy method doesn't get called.

If you wanted to recursively invoke the proxy, you could define it (let's say, as the variable name `proxy`) before returning it from the constructor, and then reference `proxy` inside the `set` method, but given the current logic, this results in a stack overflow because you'd be continually calling the proxy's setter:

```js
class darthVader {
  constructor() {
    const proxy = new Proxy(this, {
      set(obj, prop, value) {
        console.log(`Setting ${prop} to ${value}`)
        proxy[prop] = value
        return true
      }
    })
    return proxy;
  }
  set resistance(val) {
    this._resistance = val
    this.darkSide = false
  }
  get resistance() {
    return this._R2D2
  }

}

let newHero = new darthVader()
newHero.resistance = 11
console.log(newHero.darkSide)
```